# How To Print Variable To A Text File In Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello i am working on a project that prints extracted url to a text file....

I want a little help in my python program it's not working to write all the extracted url to the file whereas this writes the last url only to the file ......

```
def do_this():
    print url
    text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
    text_file.write("Extracted URL : %s" % url)

while True:
    url, n = getURL(page)
    page = page[n:]
    if url:
        do_this()
    else:
        text_file.close()
        break
```

I can't find the solution !!

Sorry For Bad English.. Please Help !!

Comment: I just wanted it to write all the extracted url from a website to a text file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a` to append, each time you open using `w` you overwrite, appending will append after any existing lines:

```
def do_this():
    print url
    text_file = open("Output.txt", "a")
    text_file.write("Purchase Amount: %s\n" % url)
```

It would probably make more sense to just open once moving the logic into the function, something like:

```
def do_this(page):
    with  open("Output.txt", "a") as f:
        while True:
            url, n = getURL(page)
            page = page[n:]
            if not url:
                break
            f.write("Extracted URL : %s\n" % url)
```

I also added a `\n` to the write or all your data will be on a single line

Comment: Perhaps a brief explanation about the difference between write and append would be beneficial.